# How to use association with find_by_sql in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, find-by-sql

I have a long SQL query, which i am using in rails Model.find_by_sql, I have to add couple of conditions in that query like i wanted to fetch all the records whose parent.is_allowed is true.

That means i am fetching all the child elements and i wanted to use association which is between child and parent.And in the Child table we have the parent_id.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Model.find_by_sql("select * from models where parent_id in (select id from parents where is_allowed='true') and ... ")
```

Just replace the `...` with your original SQL query.

### Edit

Based on your comment, I think this line is more what you need:

```
Model.find_by_sql("select * from models where parent_id in (select id from users where is_allowed='true')")
```

Comment: I will try the one which you has mentioned .. join users usr ON usr.id = a.parent_id AND usr.is_allowed = true. This sort of condition i am looking for.

Comment: Do you want a collection of users or whatever "a" is?

Comment: I basically wanted to fetch all the children whose parent is_allowed value is true..